# Cортировка слияниeм и сложность

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, сложность

[image]

Ее сложность O(N log N), откуда log N - я понимаю на примере поиска - количество строк (уровней) до 1го элемента, но почему домножают на N, не совсем понятно. К примеру обработка двух пар на второй строке, это O(N), а на третьей O(N) + O(N). (N в контексте уровня)

Или из за сложения получается O(2N), для третьей строки и 2 они откидывают? 2 можно заменить буквой зависящей от N, а так как она относительна N почему бы ее не оставить? Почему она не важна? Что то я не так понял или перепутал, или незаметил, помогите.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы правильно поняли, что глубина рекурсии будет `logn`, но на каждом уровне в любом случае будут сливаться в сумме n элементов (на втором уровне `2*(N/2)`, на третьем `4*(N/4)`, это всё отчётливо видно на картинке. То есть 2*(N/2) будет N, поэтому на каждом уровне в сумме выходит слияние n элементов, просто в более маленьких группах.

Исходя из этого мы можем понять, что `n` элементов массива будут сливаться `logn` раз, отсюда и сложность `nlogn`

[image: Описание на картинке]

Как мы можем увидеть на этой картинке, на каждом уровне рекурсии побывают все n элементов, просто каждый раз они будут сливаться сначала в более маленьких группах, потом размер группы при слиянии будет постепенно увеличиваться (т.к. сначала происходит 2 рекурсивных вызова, а только потом выполняется слияние)

Comment: Спасибо, понял где был не прав.